# Cannot watch a Angular directive attribute

Tags: javascript, angularjs, animation, angularjs-directive, require

I am building a AngularJs app with RequireJs and trying to make a animation like:
https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-animating-the-angular-way/

I load all vendor JS Files with HeadJs.

Iam facing 2 problems:
1) When I click on

foo

or

bar

, the directive seems unable to detect value in animate-when changes except the very first time when page loads.

2) Even the time directive response to value in animate-when, the animation is not triggered. I check it added a class to element. Why no animation? I tried to put TweenMax command to directive directly and animation shows which TweenMax is working.

This problem tortured me for the last few hours. Developing with AngularJs somehow frustured me semdomly although it is very powerful. Hope someone can help me out. Thank you so much.

Here is part of the HTML:

```
<section data-ng-controller="HomePageController">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li ng-click="a=true; b=false">foo</li>
            <li ng-click="b=true; a=false">bar</li>
        </ul>
        <hr>
        <section animate-when="{{ showA }}" data-animate-class="showExpand"></section>
        <section animate-when="{{ showB }}" data-animate-class="showExpand"></section>
    </nav>
</section>
```

Both showA and showB are attributes in HomePageController:

```
$scope.showA = true;
$scope.showB = false;
```

Module:

```
(function (define, angular) {
    "use strict";

    define(['controllers/HomePageController',
    'directives/animateWhen',
    'animations/showExpand'
    ],
    function (HomePageController, animateWhen, showExpand) {
    var moduleName = "page";

    angular.module(moduleName, ["ngAnimate"])
    .controller("HomePageController", HomePageController)
    .animation(".showExpand", showExpand)
    .directive("animateWhen", animateWhen);
    return moduleName;
    });

}(define, angular));
```

showExpand Animation:

```
(function (define) {
    define([''], function () {
        var showExpand = function () {
            return {
                addClass: function(element, className){
                    //not running
                    console.log("startAdding");
                    TweenMax.to(element, 1, {opacity:0});
                },
                removeClass: function(element, className){
                    //not running either
                    console.log("startRemoving");
                    TweenMax.to(element, 1, {opacity:0});
                }
            }
        };

        return [ showExpand ];
    });
}(define));
```

And here is the animateWhen directive:

```
(function (define) {
    define([''], function () {
        var animateWhen = function ($animate) {
            return function(scope, element, attrs){
                scope.$watch(attrs.watch, function(value){
                    if(value){
                        console.log("add"); //run once only when page is load
                        TweenMax.to(element, 1, {opacity:1});
                        $animate.addClass(element, attrs.animateClass);
                    } else {
                        console.log("remove"); //same, run once only
                        TweenMax.to(element, 1, {opacity:0});
                        $animate.removeClass(element, attrs.animateClass);
                    }
                }, true);
            }
        };

        return [ "$animate", animateWhen ];
    });
}(define));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For watching directive attributes you need to use `attrs.$observe`, since there is no `watch` property in the scope (you don't even have an isolate scope).

Try:

```
attrs.$observe("watch", function(value){

};
```

instead.

Comment: My god I am close to the anwser at yesterday night. I really need to spend a lot of time to study how it works. Thank you for helping.